# How do I leave Google feedback about one of its features?

Tags: google-account

I'd like to leave Google some feedback on 2-step verification, but I can't find an obvious place to do so.

Where should I leave this feedback? More generally, where does one give Google feedback about one of its products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most products, go to the product's Known Issues help page. For example, Known Issues for Google Accounts (which includes 2-step verification) is at http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/static.py?page=known_issues.cs.

There you can either vote for a known issue by expanding the issue and clicking "Report", or submit a new issue by clicking on the "let us know" link at the bottom.